# Get data from link

Tags: php, html, url

I'm trying to get a unique code from a link that I email out. The link that I send is "website.com/redeem.php?code=xxxxxxxxxx" I'm trying to capture the x's in order to compare it to a list of codes in a text document. Any help is appreciated. My knowledge of php is little.

The only thing I knew to try:

```
$code=$_POST['code'];

echo $code;
```

Comment: `?code=...` params provides as a `$_GET` array in php. Try `$_GET['code']`

Comment: In your PHP file `echo $_GET['code']` and you'll see the value of your x's

Comment: Don't you need to use $_GET instead of $_POST?

Comment: *"in order to compare it to a list of codes in a text document."* - You're working too hard. Using text files over a DB is so much work and harder to maintain, and leaves room for error, while using functions that will just make it that much more harder later on. Not to mention protecting that file from prying eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is `$_GET`.

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
echo $code;
```

Reading material:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 3):

The URL is using a querystring which is passed as `$_GET` - not `$_POST`. Try this:

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
echo $code;
```

Answer (score 1):

URI params provides as a `$_GET` array in php. Try `$_GET['code']`

You can also use `$_REQUEST` array.
It is merged `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`